# Linux : Move files that have more than 100 commas in one line

Tags: linux, sed, grep, command, move

I have 100 files in a specific directory that contains several records with fields delimited with commas.

I need to use a Linux command that check the lines in each file 
and if the line contains more than 100 comma move it to another directory.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Although my original answer below is functional, Glenn's (@glennjackman) suggestion in the comments is far more concise, idiomatic, eloquent and preferable - as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir subdir
for f in file*; do
   awk -F, 'NF>100{exit 1}' "$f" || mv "$f" subdir
done
```

It basically relies on `awk`'s exit status generally being `0`, and then only setting it to `1` when encountering files that need moving.

**Original Answer**

This will tell you if a file has more than 100 commas on any line:

```
awk -F, 'NF>100{print 1;exit} END{print 0}' someFile
```

It will print `1` and exit without parsing the remainder of the file if the file has any line with more than 100, and print `0` at the end if it doesn't.

If you want to move them as well, use

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir subdir
for f in file*; do
   if [[ $(awk -F, 'NF>100{print 1;exit}END{print 0}' "$f") != "0" ]]; then
      echo mv "$f" subdir
   fi
done
```

Try this and see if it selects the correct files, and, if you like it, remove the word `echo` and run it again so it actually moves them. Back up first!

Comment: can I move this file instead of print 1

Comment: I'd suggest using an exit value of print commands. Then: `awk 'NF>100{exit 1}' "$f" || mv ...`

Comment: @glennjackman Great suggestion, thank you. I have worked it into the answer.